# Is there a way to display more than 25 digits when outputting in Scilab?

Tags: floating-accuracy, scilab

I'm working with Scilab 5.5.2 and when using the `format` command I can display at most 25 digits of a number. **Is there a way to somehow display more than this number?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scilab operates with double precision floating point numbers; it does not support variable-precision arithmetics. Double precision means relative error of %eps, which is 2<sup>-52</sup>, approximately 2e-16.

This means you can't even get 25 correct decimal digits: when using `format(25)` you get garbage at the end. For example,

```
format(25); sqrt(3)
```

returns `1.732050807568877 1931766`

I separated the last 7 digits here because they are wrong; the correct value of `sqrt(3)` [begins with](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(3))

```
      1.732050807568877 2935274
```

Of course, if you don't mind the digits being wrong, you can have as many as you want:

```
 strcat([sprintf('%.15f', sqrt(3)), "1111111111111111111111111111111"])
```

returns `1.7320508075688771111111111111111111111111111111`.

But if you want to have arbitrary exceeding of real numbers, Scilab is not the right tool for the job (correction: [phuclv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019127) pointed out [Multiple Precision Arithmetic Toolbox](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/DD_QD) which might work for you). Out of free software packages, [mpmath Python library](http://mpmath.org/) implements arbitrary precision of real numbers: it can be used directly or via [Sagemath](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_numerical/index.html) or [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/). Commercial packages (Matlab, Maple, Mathematica) support variable precision too.

As for Scilab, I recommend using formatted print commands such as fprintf or sprintf, because they actually care about the output being meaningful. Example:  `printf('%.25f', sqrt(3))` returns

```
1.7320508075688772000000000
```

with garbage replaced by zeros. The last nonzero digit is still off by 1, but at least it's not meaningless.

Comment: I'm new to Scilab but I probably should have considered searching for a printf function. Thank you, it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Scilab uses double-precision floating-point type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37686796/995714) which has 53 bits of mantissa and can only be precise to ~15-17 digits. There's no reason printing digits beyond that.

If 25 digits of accuracy is needed then you can use a [quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) or [double-double arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) library like [ATOMS: Multiple Precision Arithmetic Toolbox details](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/DD_QD)

If you need even more precision then the only way is using an arbitrary precision library like [mpscilab](https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/mpscilab/), [Xnum](http://www.awitness.org/unifiedm/xnum.html), etc...

Comment: The keyword of my question is "display" not "calculate". I'm not looking to increase the precision of Scilab's calculations, just to display a larger number of digits, no matter how correct they are. Thank you for your answer though.