# CString to Float conversion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, type-conversion

One common question ,may be I am wrong at this point but last two hours on google not give me any answer,
Question is how to convert CString to float without using std: library in c++.

I tried with **wcstod()** function but, This function has very different behaviour.
Please find following code,

```
CString Tempconvert = "32.001";
double TempConvertedValue = wcstod(Tempconvert,NULL);
```

So, Finally **TempConvertedValue** should have value 32.001. But i am getting  **TempConvertedValue = 32.000999999999998**
Please provide me any help which convert 
String "32.001" to float 32.001 only. Without using std: library.

Comment: It looks like there is a float (instead of a double) somewhere. Floats can't express 32.001 exactly but double can. wcstod returns a double tho so the problem shouldn't be there. How do you output the value?

Comment: What's wrong with `std` library?

Comment: @JoelKlinghed This is not true, double can't express a floating point value exactly as it uses the same sort of encoding as a float but with more bits so it can hold bigger value and with more precision.

Comment: @EricFortin, true, exactly was a bad choice of word here. What I meant is that: float f = 32.001f; double d = 32.001; printf("%f %f", f, d); will print "32.000999 32.001000" ie double has enough precision to keep 32.001

Comment: @JoelKlinghed thanks for reply first of all 32.001 is a double value. i am just trying to convert string to double.And i am not getting point "How do you output the value?".

Comment: @Aryabhata, how do you see the value 32.000999999999998? By printing it? Watching the value in the debugger?

Comment: @JoelKlinghed by tool tip provided by Microsoft visual studio.Watching value in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is an example of floating point internal representation. You can have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) to see how double are stored in memory. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places) to know why debugger shows you this value.

With this storing format, it is not possible to represent a decimal number exactly. That is why money calculations usually use special decimal types that are either custom or part of the programming language.