# Double data stored in char array returns a float value

Tags: c++, c

Why is it that when I store the DATA of a double value in a char array if I get the data from the char array to another double, it returns a Float value?

In this:

```
double vals = 3.141592654;
char xvals[sizeof(vals)];
memcpy(&xvals, &vals, sizeof(xvals));

double y;
memcpy(&y, &xvals, sizeof(xvals));
std::cout<<y<<"\n";
```

OUTPUT: `3.14159`

Comment: What does `double vals = 3.141592654; std::cout<<vals <<"\n";` print?

Comment: Are you sure it returns a `float`? ISTM it is simply rounded for output.

Comment: omg yesss x3
Thanks, I got the answers below but I think it would be for a know number of decimals... So how bout if I want to return a double value from user custom values? Unknow number of decimals in the result. If for example there are 20 decimals, how can I get the number of decimals and then use std::<<cout<<std::setprecision(number_of_decimals); so I can show the full value of the double? Is there a way to get how many decimals a double has :P?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not "return a float value" : `std::cout` will simply not print all those digits by default.

you can use [`std::setprecison`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) (from `<iomanip>`) to change the number of digits to be printed :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double vals = 3.141592654;
    std::cout << vals << "\n";

    std::cout << std::setprecision(10);
    std::cout << vals;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> 3.14159
>
> 3.141592654

Comment: Ohhh I got it. So if I put setprecision with a different quantity of decimals it will make it permanent fro the next double values. Ohh I understood it :D
But what about if I get a division with unknown decimals and want to cout it?
How could I get the number of decimals in a double?

Comment: This is another task. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places

Answer (score 3):

There has been no data loss or forced conversion. The default [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) for `cout` is 6. This will give you the answer you need

```
std::cout<<std::setprecision(10)<<y<<"\n";
```

EDIT : You need to include the header `<iomanip>` for `std::setprecision`.

Comment: Thanks! :D YOu should also quote that this is included in <iomanip> :D
Thanks ^_^