# C++ Subtraction differences - why?

Tags: c++, double

I'm seeing an odd issue in my code

In my mfc/c++ application, there is a function that gets called at 2 different points. Once, when a dialog/component is displayed. The second time is when some generation is happening from a 2nd dialog/component. The only difference is that from the 2nd dialog, the call is happening in a new thread.

Within this function, broken down to its simplest, 2 doubles are subtracted.

```
double a = -13.497999999999999
double b = 33.564999999999998 
a - b
```

when I step through the code, I am getting different results from the subtraction and is having a knock on affect to other calculations. The result from Dialog 2 seems to be closer to what is valid.

```
Dialog 1 - 20.066999435424805 
Dialog 2 - 20.067000000000000
```

Very odd that simple subtraction would return different results. The differences may be minimal, but they do build up to cause a larger problem.

using VS2010, settings all correct as far as I can tell.

I've tried using floats and long double's to see if that would resolve anything but they don‘t.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `a - b` ? (I expect you meant `a + b` ?). Perhaps you should post the actual code, rather than an approximation ?

Comment: Those value cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point.

Comment: `a - b` would be -47.062999999999995, not close to either of the values you posted.

Comment: Sorry, that b should be -33.564999999999998

Answer (score 1):

According to this URL a double holds 15-16 decimal digits:

[Double precision - decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places)

`12 345678901234567
     The value -13.497999999999999 has 17 digits.`

The difference between the subtract values is only 0.000000564575195; this 
difference is within the 16 decimal digit level of precision of a double..

`1 234567890123456
0.000000564575195`

From this URL also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

There are 53 binary bits reserved for the digits in the number; this gives
15 to 17 decimal digits of precision