# C++ Random doubles from -1 to 1

Tags: c++

I need to randomly generate numbers (using random()) from -1 to 1 that are doubles. For example the output would be something like:

1,
-0.3324,
0.7821,
0.9823,
-0.111

etc... this is what I was trying to do `walk_Length = (double)rand()%2 - 1;`

Comment: I saw that tutorial, but I was wondering how can I modify that to get it to be from -1 to 1 inclusive?

Comment: It's not a "tutorial" and you should read it in full because it tells you how to give a range, with multiple approaches.

Comment: Doubles are not precise values ​​so some of the values ​​do not exist, for example 0.88 do not exist in doubles and floating. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with something like

```
double walk_Length = static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2 - 1;
```