# Decimal with extremely long number

Tags: swift

I was expecting `Decimal` to treat number like a `String` but instead I reproduced small rounding during testing.

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
let price: String? = "1535132527181273627"
let decimal: Decimal? = price != nil ? Decimal(string: price!, locale: locale) : nil
XCTAssertEqual(decimal, 1535132527181273627.0)
```

The result bothers me:

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(1535132527181274000)") is not equal to ("Optional(1535132527181273497.6)") -

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Make sure you understand what `Decimal` does. It certainly does not treat number as a `String`. It just uses decadic arithmetic. Also it doesn't support numbers of any length, it supports 35 decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and the result was:

XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(1535132527181273627)") is not equal to ("Optional(1535132527181273497.6)")

using Xcode 9.4.1 on a MacBook Pro 2015

I think the problem is in the fact that `Double` is only able to deal with 15 decimal places. So the number `1535132527181273627.0` cannot be represented accurately. Take a look at [Double precision - decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1):

This is a design problem of the Swift compiler.
It has been reported as [SR-3317](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3317) but that was closed as duplicate of [SR-920](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-920).

The problem is that the literal `1535132527181273627.0` is parsed as a `Double` literal (that is, with limited precision) even if the type should be `Decimal`. Using a `String` to initialize `Decimal` is the only workaround for now.

The solution is to redesign the built-in protocol [ExpressibleByFloatLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyfloatliteral) to allow for longer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the problem is in the test, not the code. Swift uses Double to store number from the test and it's not long enough, Decimal wasn't rounded but the number to compare in the test was.

Solution is to compare `Decimal`.

```
XCTAssertEqual(price, Decimal(string:"1535132527181273627"))
```

Comment: Why don't you make your String non optional? `let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")`
`let price = "1535132527181273627"`
`let decimal = Decimal(string: price)`

Comment: @LeoDabus it's just part of specs I am working with, price from a server is optional so I want to compare it to the same optional type in my unit test.