# double representing values upto 16 significant digits

Tags: c

I was working on reading values in variables from a byte positioned file and I had to represent some value read into decimal with 6 digits representing fractional part, total no. of digits 20.

So the value could be for example be `99999999999999999999` (20 9s) and it is to be used as float considering the last six `9s` representing fractional part.

Now when I was tring to do it with the method employed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char   c[]="999999999.999999";  //9 nines to the left of decimal and 6 nines to the right
   double d=0;

   sscanf(c,"%lf",&d);

   printf("%f\n",d);
     return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**`999999999.999999`  *same as input*

Now I increased the number of 9s to the left of decimal by 1 (making 10 nines to the left of decimal)
the output became `9999999999.999998`.

On further increase of one more 9 to the left of decimal the outcome became rounded off to `100000000000.000000`

For my usage it is possible that values with 14 digits to the left of decimal and 6 to the right of it can come in the variable - I want it to be converted precisely just like the input itself without and truncation or rounding off. Also I read somewhere that `double` can be used to represent a value with up to `16` significant digits but here when I used only `9999999999.999999` (10 nines to the left and 6 to the right) it produced outcome as `9999999999.999998` which contradicts this *represent a value with up to 16 significant digits` statement.

What should be done in this case?

Comment: Check the number of bits in the floating point representation. You've probably gone beyond the accuracy it can maintain for a decimal value converted to binary. What you read said *up to* 16 digits but there may be cases where it's just 15.

Comment: @lurker Can you please provide any credible link to read about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `total no. of digits 20` Use an integer to represent that.

Comment: @KamilCuk But last 6 digits are used for representing fractional part - integer can't be used for that.

Comment: Just multiply the number by 10^6...

Comment: @lurker **C++ Primer 5th Edition** page 62.

Comment: As much as you might wish otherwise, [`double` only stores ~15 decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: @KamilCuk 20 digits is too large for even a 64 bit integer.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus [If you consider wikipedia to be credible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) then the exact number is 15.95. And if you follow [the link for binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), there's more detail about what that number actually means. But the point is moot. A 64-bit number, whether it's a `double` or a `uint64_t`, cannot represent a 20 digit number without truncation or rounding.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus ***C++ Primer 5th Edition** page 62* The exact quote is: "The `float` and `double` types typically yield about 7
and 16 significant digits, respectively."  Note well the use of "typically" and "about".  In fact, [the standard-required definitions `FLT_DIG` and `DBL_DIG` are almost certainly 6 and 15 on your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places), so it would be accurate to say your source isn't fully correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nature of [floating point numbers is they are inaccurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems). The bigger the number, the more inaccurate.

> What should be done in this case?

You could try a `long double`, but even that's not guaranteed to be precise enough.

```
long double z = 99999999999999.999999L;
printf("%Lf\n", z);  // 100000000000000.000000
```

You could store it as an integer and remember it's actually 1,000,000 times smaller. Unfortunately, 20 digits is a bit too large for even an unsigned 64 bit integer. It's 3 bits too large.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t x = 99999999999999999999ULL;
}

test.c:4:18: error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type
    uint64_t x = 99999999999999999999ULL;
```

You could make a struct that stores the pieces separately.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
  bool positive;
  uint64_t integer;
  uint64_t decimal;
} bignum;

int main() {
    bignum num = {
        .positive = true,
        .integer = 99999999999999,
        .decimal = 999999
    };
    printf("%s" "%"PRIu64 "." "%"PRIu64 "\n",
        num.positive ? "" : "-", num.integer, num.decimal
    );
}
```

At which point you're building your own [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library. Instead, use an existing one such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). This can store numbers of any size. The trade off is speed and you have to use special types and functions.

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main() {
    mpf_t y;
    mpf_init_set_str(y, "99999999999999.999999", 10);
    gmp_printf("%Ff\n", y);
}
```

Comment: `uint64_t x = 99999999999999999999UL;` is probably better as `uint64_t x = 99999999999999999999ULL;` (`unsigned long long`) as `long` will be 32 bits on Windows even for 64-bit binaries.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks. It's good to show the proper integer constant.