# TinyXML2 Document Save Double Precision Issues

Tags: c++, precision, tinyxml2

I'm using TinyXML2 to generate XML spreadsheets, and I have a simple regression test comparing a newly generated sheet to a previously verified sheet to ensure new changes don't break the tool.
This test has been working for a while, but recently it has started failing on our CI server: the numbers in the spreadsheet generated on it have an error of about 1e-17 in magnitude or so and it's causing the file diff to fail. For reference builds in both machines are using the exact same docker container. What could be causing this discrepancy?

```
Line 243 Test: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.00073917318674313406</ss:Data>'
Line 243 Expt: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.00073917318674313396</ss:Data>'
Line 246 Test: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.00086843815746046851</ss:Data>'
Line 246 Expt: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.00086843815746046841</ss:Data>'
Line 260 Test: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.0029117682828990695</ss:Data>'
Line 260 Expt: '                    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">0.00291176828289907</ss:Data>'
```

Tried running the regression test on both local machine and CI server many times to see if issue is intermittent or consistent. Local test passed every time while CI test failed every time.

Comment: Very probably related: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places). Yes, you can end up with slightly different numbers because of slight differences between FP implementations.